# Метод в property

Tags: python, django

Часто вижу что методы у моделей превращают в property. Иногда это делают через декоратор @property, а иногда через property(method_name).

Зачем? Ведь из шаблонов они все равно вызываются без ().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вероятно, что бы можно было работать с моделью через свойства не только в шаблонах, но и, например, во view'ах.

Кроме того декоратор @property позволяет визуально отделить свойства от методов.

В упрощенном виде декоратор @property представляет из себя примерно следующий дескриптор:

```
class property(object):

    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget

    def __get__(self, obj, type = None):
        return self.fget(obj)
```

Соответственно, если у нас есть класс:

```
class Foo(object):

    def bar(self):
        return 'test1';

    @property
    def baz(self):
        return 'test2';
```

То, с точки зрения внутренней архитектуры питона, вызовы метода `bar()` свойства `baz` будут выглядеть так:

```
obj = Foo()

# это выражение полностью эквивалентно: obj.bar()
Foo.__dict__['bar'](obj)

# а это полностью эквивалентно: obj.baz
Foo.__dict__['baz'].__get__(obj)
```

Т.о. оврехэд при использовании свойств у нас будет: 1 дополнительный вызов метода `__get__()`. Т.е. почти никакого.

Comment: Есть шанс что от этого быстрее работает щаблонизатор?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо, понятно, ускорения не будет.